# (OWIN) How to get User from token?

Tags: c#, owin

**EDIT#1**

Im using OWIN for Web Api, I wonder how to get the user associated to token.
Thanks

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize()]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserFromToken()
{
User = //something
return Ok(us);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The User associated with the transaction is a property of ApiController, which your controller inherits from. You can access it like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetUserFromToken()
{
    var u = User;
    return Ok(u);
}
```

If you are interested in the user's name, you can find that with `User.Identity.Name`.